# What is a good way to turn straight edges to curves?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

Another question I want to ask is how do you extrude to both directions on the same axis?

Comment: Keep in mind that geometry to be curved must have enough subdivisions. In the case of the shown mesh long faces in the center have to be subdivided at least once.

Comment: Loosely related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36291/good-approach-to-make-planks-for-a-barrel

Comment: @luke chen To extrude in both X and Y axes only first select the loop of faces (`Alt`+`RMB`) and press `E`. Cancel operation with `RMB`, then press `S`,`Shift+Z`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- ## USING PROPORTIONAL EDITING

Add some *edge loops* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) in the middle of the object to devide the object evenly. Select the face loop in the middle (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>) and snap the cursor to it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*). Enable ***proportional editing***, then press <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to scale along X and Y axes only.
[image]

- ## USING SIMPLE DEFORM MODIFIER (STRETCH)

Give the object a ***Simple Deform*** modifier, change its mode to ***Stretch*** and adjust the deform factor as you like.
[image]

- ## USING LATTICE MODIFIER

Add a ***Lattice***, scale it to fit the object's size and subdivide it a few times. Select the object and give it a ***Lattice Modifier***. Select the points around the middle subdivision of the *lattice*, then scale them with <kbd>S</kbd>.
***NOTE:*** Adding more subdivision to the *lattice* allows you to better control the shape of the object (you can make it more uneven/realistic).
[image]

Comment: I have the biggest smile on my face right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

And there's, too, the Object Mode with **Alt C**. Proportional editing is used when, in the first place, symmetry is required. Alt C is more flexible.