# Create flat end path

Tags: path

BH

I've looked through [What is a good way to turn straight edges to curves?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81205/what-is-a-good-way-to-turn-straight-edges-to-curves) and other answers but they all deal with curving flat edges etc, I'm trying to make a path that follows the vertices exactly without curving

Blender 2.8, after adding a new "path" (standard) and moving some vertices, the finished product is curved, while I want it to just follow the vertices exactly (because I'm tracing an exact shape)

How can this be done? Setting the resolution down in the path settings helps partially, but there are still some parts that don't match exactly

Comment: Do you mean change the spline-type to 'poly'?

Comment: @robin I don't know, however I can get it straight would be great